# 2D counterpart of std::array in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, template, library

I implemented a 2D counterpart of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) named `array2d` in C++17. It is an aggregate like `std::array`, and provides similar interface. The goal is that if you know how to use `std::array`, then you will find yourself at home using `array2d`. Any comments are welcome :) For better viewing experience with highlighting, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Modern_CPP_Challenge_Solution/blob/master/17_array2d.hpp) GitHub page.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, std::size_t N0, std::size_t N1>
struct array2d {
  using row_t = std::array<T, N1>;
  inline static constexpr std::array sizes{ N0, N1 };

  static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept { return N0 * N1; }
  static constexpr bool empty() noexcept { return !size(); }

  T& at(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return data_.at(i).at(j); }
  const T& at(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const { return data_.at(i).at(j); }

  row_t& operator[](std::size_t i) noexcept { return data_[i]; }
  const row_t& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept { return data_[i]; }

  T& front() { return data_.front().front(); }
  const T& front() const { return data_.front().front(); }

  T& back() { return data_.back().back(); }
  const T& back() const { return data_.back().back(); }

  T* data() noexcept { return data_.data()->data(); }
  const T* data() const noexcept { return data_.data()->data(); }

  T* begin() noexcept { return data(); }
  const T* begin() const noexcept { return data(); }

  T* end() noexcept { return data() + size(); }
  const T* end() const noexcept { return data() + size(); }

  auto rbegin() noexcept { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end()); }
  auto rbegin() const noexcept { return std::make_reverse_iterator(end()); }

  auto rend() noexcept { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
  auto rend() const noexcept { return std::make_reverse_iterator(begin()); }

  void fill(const T& v) {
    for (auto& row : data_) {
      row.fill(v);
    }
  }

  friend void swap(array2d& a, array2d& b) { a.data_.swap(b.data_); }

  std::array<row_t, N0> data_;
};
```

Answer (score 16):

Let me collect a couple of thoughts here.

- Aggregate initialization currently works like this:

  ```
  array2d<int, 2, 2> a{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
  ```

  but wouldn't it be favorable to allow for

  ```
  array2d<int, 2, 2> a{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  ```
- [std::array::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) performs bound checking and throws upon an out of bounds index. When your intention is to stick with the `std::array` interface, you should do the same.
- If you want the container to be standard-compliant, there are some type aliases missing and maybe more. In particular, there are no `cbegin()`, `cend()`, `crbegin()`, `crend()` member functions. Is this intended?
- You implicitly use row-major order. Are you sure everyone expects this? Users familiar with Eigen and their fixed size matrices might at least want to customize row-/column-major ordering, e.g. `Eigen::Matrix<int, 2, 2, Eigen::ColMajor> m;`
- A range based for loop will considerably differ from a manual loop over rows and columns. Example:

  ```
  // Loop over elements, transposed access. Requires nested loop.
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
     for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        std::cout << a[j][i] << "\n";

  // Loop over elements, tranposed access impossible. Only one loop.
  for (const auto& i : d)
      std::cout << i << "\n";
  ```

  This is slightly unintuitive. Shouldn't the range based for loop require a nested loop as well?
- The static data member `sizes` is not used anywhere.

Getting a two-dimensional array to work is not that much of an effort. Getting the semantics right is hard. Sticking to the `std::array` interface is a good goal when ease of use is intended for those familiar with the `std::array` template. But the additional dimension pulls in requirements that can't be tackled with the concepts of `std::array`. I would recommend having a look at established linear algebra libraries and their fixed size matrices. Also, the [mdspan proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0009r6.html) for a multi-dimensional view on array types might be a good read.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code.

1) You can `a{1, 2, 3, 4}` and make a new line as you see fit.

2) `array2d::at` does bounds checking too, for `array::at` is called under the hood ^_^

3) You are right they are missing. I think they are tedious and not very useful in practice. But again, the `array2d` is not very useful either XD

4) It is by design that the layout aligns with built-in two-dimensional array.

5) I intend the loop to be similar to what it does with `array`. User needs to use other interface if different traversal is desired.

6) `sizes` is part of the interface.

Comment: `array2d` is not meant to model matrix in linear algebra. Just like `array` and `vector` are not meant to model vector in linear algebra. By design, it's only meant to serve the role of a basic fixed-size 2D container. Hopefully more convenient to use than built-in 2D array and nested `array`.

Comment: You're right with the bounds checking of course :) Also, the point that `array2d` is not meant to be used as a linear algebra vocabulary type is obviously valid. I do see two issues with that, though: if you introduce `array2d` to a code base, developers might use it for linear algebra despite the fact that you didn't design it to fit these requirements. And, I personally use two-dimensional arrays for linear algebra and nothing else. If I need more that one dimension, I often find other data structures nearer to my intention.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good! Great job.

1. To initialize the array completely I have to write:

   ```
   array2d<int, 2, 2> Array{{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}}};
   ```

   The two extra sets of braces are horrible! If you instead have a `T[][]` data member one layer of braces falls of and you need only one set of braces just like `std::array`.

   ```
   array2d<int, 2, 2> Array{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}}; // manageable
   ```
2. Whatever happened to `constexpr` all the things? :)
3. Nested `std::array`s are not guaranteed to be continuous (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762662/is-the-data-in-nested-stdarrays-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)), although in practice they probably are. Resolving point 1) also fixes this issue.
4. IMO a `at` member that takes only one index and returns a row would make sense for consistency with your `operator[]`.
5. Consider adding the various member types that a [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) is supposed to have (and also the other requirements, `cr[begin, end]`, `max_size`, member `swap`, ...).
6. I mean sure, `size` and `empty` can be `static`, but really, conceptually this doesn't make much sense. `std::array`'s `empty` and `size` are not static too.
7. How about providing various customization points of `std::get`, `std::tuple_size`, ... so that your array works with structured bindings.
8. You didn't add any relational operators. Is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code, Rakete. 1) Since C++14, you can simply `Array{1, 2, 4, 5}` without any nested braces. 2) You are right they are missing. It's tedious and a burden, and I don't think they are very useful in practice. So I don't bother :/ 3) Good catch. Today I learned. 4) On a second thought, agreed. We can have `at` overloads that take 1 and 2 indices ^_^ 5) Yes. For serious production code, they should be present. The boring part of writing C++ library code XD

Comment: 6) User can still invoke them the way as if they are non-static like `a.size()`. Making them `static` provides more possibilities, and removes the need to pass `this`. 7) You are right. 8) Not until [`operator<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) is practically supported by the compilers :P

Comment: @Lingxi 1) How did I not know that, thanks :) 2) you really should, it's only one keyword ;) 6) yeah, but still thinks it's weird. 8) that would require that T also has an operator<=>. If it has the traditional operators, then you won't be able to compare the array since operator<=> can't dispatch to the individual relational operators of T.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I believe `operator<=>` can dispatch to the traditional operators now.